# How to solve coupled differential equation in matlab using ode45

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, ode45

I have two differential equations: da/dt=a(.3/a^3+.7)^1/2 and dτ/dt=1/a. The initial conditions are t=0; a=1 and τ=0, respectively. How can I solve the equations in Matlab? I need to calculate different values of a, t and τ also plot τ vs a. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's quite easy.

First write a function to implement your differential equation and save it with a filename corresponding to the function name:

```
function dy = my_ode(t,y)
dy(1) = y(1)*(0.3/y(1)^3 + 0.)^(1/2); % a
dy(2) = 1/dy(1); % tau
```

Then in MATLAB, call the `ode45` solver with your function

```
[t,y] = ode45(@my_ode,[0 10],[1; 0]);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. Actually, I have to plot /tau vs a. Can you kindly show, how can I plot that?

Comment: Yes, once you have the ode solved, your results are stored in the variable `y`, with `y(1)` being `a`, and `y(2)` being `tau`. Just plot one versus the other.

Comment: Correction: `y(:,1)` is `a` and `y(:,2)` is `tau` as `y` is a matrix of `n`x`2` where `n` is the number of time values.

Comment: PS: you may want to look at the [documentation for `ode45`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) and familiarise yourself with how to solve odes in MATLAB.